# How to change combobox value on Datagridview when another combobox value change in same datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

**I have datagridview with two comboxbox** if one comboxbox value change according to 1 combobox value another combo box value fill.

i have table Country if country india is select from 1 comboxbox. state, and state_code fill in another **comboxbox in datagridview.** Code is in vb.net